# Adding an ID column based on two other columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cursors, rank

I have a query which returns output as follows:

```
 [Location] [Reference] [Year] [Int1] [Int2]
    England           1   2015     13    201
    England           1   2015     12     57
    England           1   2015      4     14
    England           2   2015     18     29
    England           2   2015     18     29
    England           1   2016     32     67
    England           1   2016     43     11
    England           2   2016     10     56
```

Where the int1 and int2 columns represent some calculated data regarding the locations.
I am trying to represent the data in a report and realized I could use an ID column of the form:

```
 [ID][Location] [Reference] [Year] [Int1] [Int2]
    1   England           1   2015     13    201
    2   England           1   2015     12     57
    3   England           1   2015      4     14
    1   England           2   2015     18     29
    2   England           2   2015     33     12
    1   England           1   2016     32     67
    2   England           1   2016     43     11
    1   England           2   2016     10     56
```

Which is incremented for every row which has the same Reference and Year values.

I have so far tried to achieve this using the Ranking functions as in the example below but with little luck.

```
SELECT Location, Reference, Year, Int1, Int2,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY Reference ASC) AS rnk
FROM Value
```

Returns

```
 [Location] [Reference] [Year] [Int1] [Int2][rnk]
    England           1   2015     13    201    1
    England           1   2015     12     57    1
    England           1   2015      4     14    1
    England           2   2015     18     29    2
    England           2   2015     33     12    2
    England           1   2016     32     67    1
    England           1   2016     43     11    1
    England           2   2016     10     56    2
```

So my question would be is there a way to use the rank functions, Rank, DENSE_RANK etc in order to achieve this? Failing that what might my best option be?

It has been suggested that a CURSOR may help me order the data in this way but after reading up on its use I would like to determine whether a set based approach is available.

I tried to create an SQLFiddle for this question but it seems I can't create a SQL Server version at the moment. I've created the [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d74c1e/1) using MySQL 5.6 so you at least have access to the schema. Apologies.

Comment: Prefer Postgres next time (that SQL Server in SQLfiddle doesn't work.) It has all the window functions and many other features (that MySQL doesn't): [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aaa8be/2)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ or this one works for SQL Server http://rextester.com/HNO24072

Comment: Thank you both. I'll bear the Postgre point in mind and I'll give rextester a try later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need

```
SELECT Location, 
       Reference, 
       Year,  
       Int1, 
       Int2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Year, Reference 
                              ORDER BY Int2 DESC) AS [Id]
FROM Value
```

To give your desired results ([online demo)](http://rextester.com/HNO24072).

In the event of tied Year,Reference,Int2 this will arbitrarily assign a sequential numbering between the tied rows.